# Hyperref and Automatic Citation indexing

Tags: hyperref, citing, back-referencing

I am using `hyperref` package with `backref` option

```
\usepackage[bookmarks=true, backref, allbordercolors = green]{hyperref}
```

It generated references at the end of IEEE style document with a roman numeral at the end of each citation. It is the link to section in the paper where the reference was used. 
For eg. the verbatim text appearing in the reference section as:

> P. Lecocq, P. Gautron, J.-E. Marvie, and G. Sourimant, “Subpixel
>   shadow mapping,” in ACM SIGGRAPH 2013 Talks. ACM, 2013, p. 19. **II**

Do you know if the **II** in the end causes problem with automatic citation counters like Google Scholar, ACM, and others?

Comment: Should this posting maybe be moved to another SE group, say to Stack Overflow? It doesn't seem to be related all that closely to TeX and friends.

Comment: This question is not in the main stream, but I have just voted against closing it. Let us give the community a chance of guiding the new user.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer If you read the question again, do you really think a MWE is necessary in this case?

Comment: I'd avoid the naked page number at the end: “Cited on page 11” keeps ambiguities off.

Comment: Mixed feelings here: I do understand where the OP's question is coming from, but as @Mico, I also feel this question is not for TeX.stackexchange.com per se.

Comment: ..and I also second egreg: to avoid any problems, switch to `arabic` and get on with it :)